# Make Lubuntu wireless driver solution persistent

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, broadcom

I installed Lubuntu in a USB 3.0 16GB Flash Drive, and it worked fine.

The only problem that I had was with my Broadcom 802.11n Wireless Driver, it was not being recognized and I solved using the driver provided in the Broadcom's official website.

I used the "offline" method, using XTERM command's:

```
make
modprobe lib80211
modprobe cfg80211
insmod wl.ko
```

And it worked!

BUT, I have to do it, EVERY TIME I restart my computer :(

I was thinking about developing a shell script to execute the commands, but, is there another way?

(It surely is persistent)

Info added: I installed full system on the flash drive, it requires my password when I start it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running 'Additional Drivers'?

Menu>Preferences>Additional Drivers

This will give you the option to install proprietary drivers that aren't included in the OS install image

Comment: I didn't, I will try it and answer here in a few minutes.